# Parse type of connection from String in Java

Tags: java

Is there a library or a simple method (probably I need to use regex) to check if a string contains an address and if affermative return the type of the connection. It could be HTTP, HTTPS, JDBC, TCP/IP.

Comment: What does a String that connects via TCP look like?

Answer (score 0):

The [`getProtocol()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getProtocol--) method of [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) does what you want. Oracle have a [tutorial on parsing URLs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) that you might want to read too.